# Determine which input with class is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

On button click, I'm checking if any input with the class 'req' is empty. I want to change the border of only the empty inputs to red. Here is my code.

```
$('#btnUpdateOrder').click(function () {
        if ($('.req').attr('value').trim() == '') {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
            alert('All fields in the ship to and bill to areas must be completed');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But my code makes the button's border red, not the input. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should never use `.attr('value')` but rather `.val()` to get the value.

Comment: Actually, .val() doesn't work with text boxes.

Comment: @boruchsiper - Yes, it does. It should work with any element that supports the `value` attribute.

Comment: I admit I was wrong. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the button. You could use `filter` to reduce the matched set of elements to those that are empty and then apply the CSS to that set:

```
$(".req").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) === "";
}).css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Note that I've used the jQuery `trim` function because the native function is not available in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$('.req')` instead of `$(this)`:

```
$('#btnUpdateOrder').click(function() {
    $('.req').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val().trim() == '';
    }).css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

Comment: I would do that, except this will make all the inputs with class 'req' have a red border. I need only for the empty inputs to have the red border. Thanks for trying.